# Problema al instalar el modulo cffi-1.7.0 y la libreria libmagic de Python:

Tags: python, librería, instalacion, modulos

***Introducción al problema:***

Requiero **instalar la librería** **libmagic, de Python**, para un proyecto...

Anteriormente ejecute "pip install libmagic" pero no fue lo que requería ya que al correr el script saltaba este error de importación:

```
  File "c:\users\matii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\magic\loader.py", line 39, in load_lib
      raise ImportError('failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation')
  ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation
```

Por esto creo que debo instalar la libreria mediante "pip install python-libmagic"...

Cuando intento instalarla mediante: "pip install python-libmagic" salta un error.
El origen de este, es que **para la instalación se requiere el modulo cffi en su versión 1.7.0** y *no la versión actual(cffi-1.15.0)*, esto se debe a que la ultima actualización de la librería libmagic fue en "jul 7, 2016", fecha en la que lanzo el modulo cffi-1.7.0...

******Problema***:***

El problema real surge al intentar descargar el modulo cffi en su version 1.7.0 mediante el comando: "pip install cffi==1.7.0"

Adjunto el error arrojado desde la cmd al ejecutar el comando "pip install cffi==1.7.0":

```
   Collecting cffi==1.7.0
   
   Using cached cffi-1.7.0.tar.gz (400 kB)

   Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\matii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38- 
    32\lib\site-packages (from cffi==1.7.0) (2.20)   

   Building wheels for collected packages: cffi

         Building wheel for cffi (setup.py) ... error

         ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

          command: 'c:\users\matii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 
         'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 
          '"'"'C:\\Users\\Matii\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
          2ei29j1u\\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\\setup.py'"'"'; 
           __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Matii\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
          2ei29j1u\\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, 
          '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
           '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 
           'C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-so6qnh8n'

   cwd: C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\
      Complete output (45 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\api.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\backend_ctypes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\cffi_opcode.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\commontypes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\cparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\ffiplatform.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\lock.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\model.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\recompiler.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\setuptools_ext.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\vengine_cpy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\vengine_gen.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\verifier.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\_cffi_include.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\parse_c_type.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      copying cffi\_embedding.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
      running build_ext
      building '_cffi_backend' extension
      creating build\temp.win32-3.8
      creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
      creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\c
      creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\c\libffi_msvc
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
      Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL 
      /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic/libffi_msvc -Ic:\users\matii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include 
      -Ic:\users\matii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files 
      (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include" "- 
      IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
      Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
      Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
      Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
      Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
      Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
      Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows 
      Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcc/_cffi_backend.c /Fobuild\temp.win32- 
      3.8\Release\c/_cffi_backend.obj
     _cffi_backend.c
      C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
      2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\minibuffer.h(66): warning C4996: 
     'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
      C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
      2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\file_emulator.h(54): warning C4090: '=': 
      distintos calificadores 'const'
      c/_cffi_backend.c(4251): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GetSize': deprecated in 3.3
      c/_cffi_backend.c(4283): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GetSize': deprecated in 3.3
      c/_cffi_backend.c(4353): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GetSize': deprecated in 3.3
      C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
      2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\ffi_obj.c(191): warning C4090: 
      'inicializando': distintos calificadores 'const'
      C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
      2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\lib_obj.c(129): warning C4090: 
      'inicializando': distintos calificadores 'const'
       C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
       2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\lib_obj.c(208): warning C4090: 
      'inicializando': distintos calificadores 'const'
      C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
        2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\lib_obj.c(506): warning C4090: '=': 
        distintos calificadores 'const'
      C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
       2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\call_python.c(20): error C2037: a la 
       izquierda de 'builtins' se especifica '_is' struct/union sin definir
      C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
       2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\call_python.c(73): warning C4090: '=': 
       distintos calificador es 'const'
      C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
       2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\call_python.c(160): error C2037: a la 
       izquierda de 'modules' se especifica '_is' struct/union sin definir
      C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
       2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\call_python.c(235): error C2037: a la 
       izquierda de 'modules' se especifica '_is' struct/union sin definir

     error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual 
        Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed 
        with exit status 2

        ----------------------------------------
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for cffi
```

Adjunto continuacion del error...:

```
      Running setup.py clean for cffi
      
      Failed to build cffi

      Installing collected packages: cffi

      Attempting uninstall: cffi

      Found existing installation: cffi 1.14.5
  
      Uninstalling cffi-1.14.5:
      
      Successfully uninstalled cffi-1.14.5
      Running setup.py install for cffi ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\matii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Matii\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2ei29j1u\\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Matii\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2ei29j1u\\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-c1yijq_x\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\matii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\cffi'
     cwd: C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\
Complete output (45 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.8
creating build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\api.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\backend_ctypes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\cffi_opcode.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\commontypes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\cparser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\ffiplatform.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\lock.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\model.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\recompiler.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\setuptools_ext.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\vengine_cpy.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\vengine_gen.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\verifier.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\_cffi_include.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\parse_c_type.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
copying cffi\_embedding.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\cffi
running build_ext
building '_cffi_backend' extension
creating build\temp.win32-3.8
creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\c
creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\c\libffi_msvc
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic/libffi_msvc -Ic:\users\matii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\matii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcc/_cffi_backend.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\c/_cffi_backend.obj
_cffi_backend.c
C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\minibuffer.h(66): warning C4996: 'PyObject_AsReadBuffer': deprecated in 3.0
C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\file_emulator.h(54): warning C4090: '=': distintos calificadores 'const'
c/_cffi_backend.c(4251): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GetSize': deprecated in 3.3
c/_cffi_backend.c(4283): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GetSize': deprecated in 3.3
c/_cffi_backend.c(4353): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GetSize': deprecated in 3.3
C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\ffi_obj.c(191): warning C4090: 'inicializando': distintos calificadores 'const'
C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\lib_obj.c(129): warning C4090: 'inicializando': distintos calificadores 'const'
C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\lib_obj.c(208): warning C4090: 'inicializando': distintos calificadores 'const'
C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\lib_obj.c(506): warning C4090: '=': distintos calificadores 'const'
C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\call_python.c(20): error C2037: a la izquierda de 'builtins' se especifica '_is' struct/union sin definir
C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\call_python.c(73): warning C4090: '=': distintos calificadores 'const'
C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\call_python.c(160): error C2037: a la izquierda de 'modules' se especifica '_is' struct/union sin definir
C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2ei29j1u\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\c\call_python.c(235): error C2037: a la izquierda de 'modules' se especifica '_is' struct/union sin definir
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
----------------------------------------

   Rolling back uninstall of cffi

   Moving to c:\users\matii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site- 
    packages\_cffi_backend.cp38-win32.pyd

   from C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-bnzpqw4o\_cffi_backend.cp38-win32.pyd
  
   Moving to c:\users\matii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\cffi- 
   1.14.5.dist-info\

   from C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\~ffi-1.14.5.dist- 
      info

  Moving to c:\users\matii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\cffi\

  from C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\~ffi
   
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 
   
  'c:\users\matii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, 
   setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Matii\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
   2ei29j1u\\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\\setup.py'"'"'; 
   __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Matii\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
   2ei29j1u\\cffi_dd5f42699429433f96b88e07181c1a66\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', 
   open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
   __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Matii\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record- 
  c1yijq_x\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 
  'c:\users\matii\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\cffi' Check the logs for full 
  command output.
```

Para intentar solucionar este problema he intentado lo siguiente:

- Descargar e instalar el modulo cffi-1.7.0 mediante "pip install cffi-1.7.0.tar.gz" (Descargando el archivo desde "https://pypi.org/project/cffi/1.7.0/#files")
- Descargar e instalar la librería libmagic-0.4.0 mediante "pip install python-libmagic-0.4.0.tar.gz" (Descargando el archivo desde "https://pypi.org/project/python-libmagic/#files")
- Actualizar setuptools "pip install -U setuptools"
- Actualizar pip "python -m pip install --upgrade pip"
- Instalar "Herramientas de compilación de C++" mediante "Visual Studio Build Tools 2019"

Como era de esperarse, el realizar estos pasos, no soluciono mi problema...

¿De que forma puedo solucionar este problema?

Info adicional:

Python: "3.8.3"(versión)

SO: Windows 10pro

Comment: ¿Intentó `pip install python-magic`  `pip install python-magic-bin` ? Leí algunos Issues en GitHub, de otros módulos, y resolvían con la segunda opción. Slds

Comment: @eniel.rod No, no lo había intentado con anterioridad, pero lo acabo de intentar y si... si me funciono!!! Gracias!!

Comment: Con gusto Mati! Ah, añadí mi comentario como respuesta para que aparezca como solucionada, si puede le da en aceptar. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intente `pip install python-magic` `pip install python-magic-bin`.
En algunos Issues planteados en GitHub, de otros módulos pero relacionados con libmagic, resolvían con esto, algunos con la segunda opción.